# What to change in this program so it produces a good output?

Tags: c#

The following code was taken from the book I'm studying and they say that the last half of the output should be in upper case, thanks to OnCarEngineEvent2. However when i compiled the program it wasn't the case. Why it doesn't work and what is needed to be changed? Thanks.

```
public class Car
{
// Internal state data.
public int CurrentSpeed { get; set; }
public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
public string PetName { get; set; }

// Is the car alive or dead?
private bool carIsDead;

// Class constructors.
public Car() { MaxSpeed = 100; }
public Car(string name, int maxSp, int currSp)
{
    CurrentSpeed = currSp;
    MaxSpeed = maxSp;
    PetName = name;
}


// 1) Define a delegate type.
public delegate void CarEngineHandler(string msgForCaller);

// 2) Define a member variable of this delegate.
private CarEngineHandler listOfHandlers;

// 3) Add registration function for the caller.
public void RegisterWithCarEngine(CarEngineHandler methodToCall)
{
    // listOfHandlers = methodToCall;
    // listOfHandlers += methodToCall; 
    // listOfHandlers += methodToCall; 
    if (listOfHandlers == null)
        listOfHandlers = methodToCall;
    else
        Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall);
}


// 4) Implement the Accelerate() method to invoke the delegate’s 
//    invocation list under the correct circumstances.
public void Accelerate(int delta)
{
    // If this car is 'dead', send dead message.
    if (carIsDead)
    {
        if (listOfHandlers != null)
            listOfHandlers("Sorry, this car is dead...");
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentSpeed += delta;

        // Is this car 'almost dead'?
        if (10 == (MaxSpeed - CurrentSpeed)
            && listOfHandlers != null)
        {
            listOfHandlers("Careful buddy!  Gonna blow!");
        }

        if (CurrentSpeed >= MaxSpeed)
            carIsDead = true;
        else
            Console.WriteLine("CurrentSpeed = {0}", CurrentSpeed);
    }
}

}


class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***** Delegates as event enablers *****\n");

        // First, make a Car object.
        Car c1 = new Car("SlugBug", 100, 10);
        c1.RegisterWithCarEngine(new Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent));

        // This time, hold onto the delegate object,
        // so we can unregister later. 
        Car.CarEngineHandler handler2 = new Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent2);
        c1.RegisterWithCarEngine(handler2);

        // Speed up (this will trigger the events).
        Console.WriteLine("***** Speeding up *****");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            c1.Accelerate(20);

        // We won't see the 'uppercase' message anymore!
        Console.WriteLine("***** Speeding up *****");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            c1.Accelerate(20);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    #region Delegate targets
    // We now have TWO methods that will be called by the Car
    // when sending notifications. 
    public static void OnCarEngineEvent( string msg )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n***** Message From Car Object *****");
        Console.WriteLine("=> {0}", msg);
        Console.WriteLine("***********************************\n");
    }

    public static void OnCarEngineEvent2( string msg )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=> {0}", msg.ToUpper());
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What's not working here? Please help us narrow down the cause of the problem by first saying what it is.

Comment: @AntonieBlom  the last 6 messages "the car is dead" should be in upper case and others in lower case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your `RegisterWithCarEngine` method. Currently, if an event handler is already attached, you call `Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall)` but you don't update `listOfHandlers`.

Use `listOfHandlers += (CarEngineHandler)Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall);`

This could also be simplified to;

```
 // 3) Add registration function for the caller.
public void RegisterWithCarEngine(CarEngineHandler methodToCall)
{
    listOfHandlers += methodToCall;
}
```

But remember **this won't detach the previous handler**, so you'll display both lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: like ebyrob said I'm " wondering why only one event handler is being called, not how to modify code to output upper case". So this answer don't really help me :(

Comment: @user1968256 Sorry, thought it was clear. I'll try to explain better: when you try attach your second handler, you actually do nothing as you don't take the result of Delegate.Combine into account. So you don't attach your second handler, so it won't be ever called.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void RegisterWithCarEngine(CarEngineHandler methodToCall)
{
    if (listOfHandlers == null)
        listOfHandlers = methodToCall;
    else
        listOfHandlers += (CarEngineHandler)Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if (listOfHandlers == null)
                listOfHandlers = methodToCall;
            else
                listOfHandlers = (CarEngineHandler)Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall); 
//It will be better then += in with context ;)

Comment: Um... I don't think changing `+=` to `=` will allow event handler/delegate hookup at all, given how `Delegate` defines its operators.

Comment: I test it ;) So don't think - proof it ;) {if (listOfHandlers == null) listOfHandlers = methodToCall; else listOfHandlers = (CarEngineHandler)Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall);} is same to listOfHandles += methodToCall;

Comment: Changing "+=" to "=" Fix error with duplicates listOfHandlers: Where result listOfHandlers: were {listOfHandlers += listOfHandlers; listOfHandlers += methodToCall} but needed  listOfHandlers += methodToCall ;)

Comment: Then add those explanations to the answer by [edit]ing, please; comments are not permanent.